# how to insert the language id in a typolink in typoscript

Tags: typo3, config, typoscript, typolink

i want to add the language id in a typolink

so far

```
    LOGO = COA
    LOGO {
        10 = TEXT
        10 {
            value = logo
            typolink {
                parameter = 116
                additionalParams = &L={$config.sys_language_uid}
            }
        }
    }
```

if `L=4` it's working

but if i use `L={$config.sys_language_uid}` it gets ignored altogether

same with `L=GP:L` 
and `L=GPvar:L`

what would be the proper syntax here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

working if i do something like

```
                additionalParams = COA
                additionalParams {
                  10 = TEXT
                  10.data = GP : L
                  10.intval = 1
                  10.wrap = &L=|
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to do that on your own. With the following global TypoScript configuration the parameter L will added to every link:

```
config.linkVars = L(int)
```

So, if you use `HMENU.special = language` this will be managed on the switch automatically, too:)

http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html

Comment: that link is not part of any menu and the url has to change along with the root page

Comment: alex, just try out config.linkVars = L(int) in your main TypoScript Setup

Comment: `config {
    linkVars = L(0-10)
    uniqueLinkVars = 1
}`   it's there this problem is solved !

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about {$config.sys_language_uid}, but your code will output it as plain text. In order to use variables like {GP:L}, you got to dataWrap it or insert "insertData" after the value.

```
10 = TEXT
10 {
    value = logo
    typolink {
        parameter = 116
        additionalParams.dataWrap = &L={GP:L}
    }
}
```

OR (the best way I'd say):

```
10 = TEXT
10 {
    value = logo
    typolink {
        parameter = 116
        additionalParams.cObject = TEXT
        additionalParams.cObject {
            wrap = &L=|
            data = GP:L
        }
    }
}
```

Using {TSFE:sys_language_uid} might be a better option if you are querying the database.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make a cObject or COA

```
additionalParams = type=0&L={GP:L}
additionalParams.insertData = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this kind of URL using `addQueryString = 1`. https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Typolink/Index.html#addquerystring

Comment: this doesn't help at all for the given problem.